# Why does ```typeof(a) != Number``` //evaluate True - even when typeof(a)==Number?

Tags: javascript, typeof

Student of The Odin Project Here

https://github.com/TheOdinProject/javascript-exercises/tree/solutions/sumAll

I managed to get the sum part of it work (so it's only the first if statement that is the problem)

They want "ERROR" returned if a non-number is passed as either a or b , or if a or b is a negative number.

I used the code below.

First if statement is evaluating to true even if both a and b are numbers

Their solution was to use !Number.isInteger(a)||!Number.isInteger(b)

Any ideas why the first if statement done as below does not work as intended

If I `console.log(a)` it logs number

```
const sumAll = function(a,b) {
    let c =0
    if((a||b)<0 || (typeof(a)||typeof(b)) !=Number){
        return "ERROR"
    }
    else if(a<b){
   for(let i=a; i<=b; i++){
       c += i;
   }
   return c ;
   }else if(a>b){for(let i=b; i<=a; i++){
    c += i;
   }
   return c;
   }
   };
```

Comment: typeof returns a **string** - also `typeof(a)||typeof(b)` ALWAYS results in the type of `a` - `a||b` will never `< 0` ... unless `a === 0` and `b < 0` - which I'm sure is not what you meant ... i.e. `(a||b) < 0` does not test if a or b is less than 0 - you'd want `a<0 || b < 0` and you'd want to test that AFTER checking if they are numbers

Comment: `console.log(typeof 4, typeof 4 != Number)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to individually check for a<0 and b<0, you cannot do `(a||b)<0`. Reason: `a||b` gets evaluated first and you get the first truthy value out of a and b. So, it becomes a matter of order. If you pass `1,-2` you will get `1` as your result of `a||b` and obviously `1<0` return false.

```js
function func(a,b){
console.log(a||b);
console.log((a||b)<0);
}

func(1,-2);
func(-1,2);
func(1,2);
```

Similar problem with `(typeof(a)||typeof(b)) !=Number`. You are supposed to individually check `((typeof(a) != 'number') || (typeof(b) != 'number'))`.
Notice how I have changed `Number` to `'number'`. `typeof` returns a string as mentioned in comments.

You need to amend your if conditions accordingly.